# How to create doctrine records with an id using Behat and tablenode in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, behat

I have the following feature:

```
Scenario: Product page
    Given there are the following products:
      | id | name          | price |
      | 1 | Test product  | 100   |
    When I am on "/product/view/1"
    Then the main page title should be "Test product"
```

Now, I'm using Symfony with Doctrine. So in my context class I can not do this:

```
/**
     * @Given /^there are the following products:$/
     */
    public function createProducts(TableNode $products)
    {

        $hash = $users->getHash();
        foreach ($hash as $row) {
            // Create our user and set details
            $product = new Product();
                        $product->setId($row['id']); // <= This method doesn't exist
            $product->setName($row['name']);
            $product->setPrice($row['price']);

            // Persist product...
        }
    }
```

The setId method does not exist and it doesn't look like a good idea to create it. So my question is, is there any way to test this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use another approach:

```
Scenario: Product page
Given there are the following products:
  | name          | price |
  | Test product  | 100   |
When I am on the "Test product" page
Then the main page title should be "Test product"
```

Step `I am on the "Test product" page` should be like this:

```
    $product = $this->getService('your_product_repo')->findOneBy(array('name' => $productName));

    $url = $this->getService('router')->generate('your_product_page_route', array('id' => $product->getId()));

    $this->getSession()->visit($url);
```

This might not work out of the box, but it gives you an idea.

This way if you ever change the product route, this scenario will not be affected.

Comment: Hi, that's a good idea. Problem is we want to have some tests to specifically test URL (SEO stuff). So that way the SEO can create tests to verify that, i.e., the url /product/view/323 does a 301 redirection to product-view/323

Comment: use the same approach: when I go to the product page, then I should be on the redirected page. First step would generate '/product/view/323' and visit it, the second step would check that current uri is 'product-view/323'.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DataFixtures](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html) for that kind of tasks.

You could easily create test data and populate your test db accordly

Comment: I'd like to avoid using data fixtures as they don't really belong to the test. Data fixtures are great but the whole point for us using behat is that the features files can be understand by developers, QA and product owners. If we mix the data fixtures in the process QA and PO will be left aside

Comment: @petekaner of course this is not the point. You're saying here how to retrieve data (you're trying to set up ids, don't you?) and not how to specify them into scenarios. Let's think about that last thing